# MySQLSyntaxErrorException while trying to update database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm doing an app for school project and I came across this error I've tried to figure it out but I can't seem to fix it.

Let me explain the problem first, basically I'm trying to update previously created user. Initially the profile has only username and a password. I want the user to be able to add whatever details he wishes to later on once he has created his own profile.

I have one class which has the database connectivity and update Profile method. The other class is a jFrame where user can input some data into textfields and the intention is that it will be inserted into fields for existing profile within the database (Initially those fields are declared as null).

Below you can see my DBConnect class which contain the Login method and UpdateProfile method. In the login method I'm creating a profile object which holds all the variables and methods such as getUsername, getPassword etc.

public class DBConnect {

```
private Connection dbConnection;
public  Profile profile;

public DBConnect() {

    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototype?user=root");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed :" + ex);
    }
}

public void Login() {
    profile = new Profile(LoginWindow.usernameField.getText(), LoginWindow.passwordField.getText());
    Statement userQuery = null;
    try {
        //Look for the user with valid username and password
        userQuery = dbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = userQuery.executeQuery("Select * FROM Profile WHERE pName = \"" + profile.getUsername() + "\" and password = \"" + profile.getPassword() + "\"");
        if (rs.next()) {
            profile.isLoggedin(true);
        } else {
            profile.isLoggedin(false);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        profile.isLoggedin(false);
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (userQuery != null) {
                userQuery.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to close login query");
        }
    }
}

public void updateProfile(String _height, String _weight, String _goalWeight, String _age) {
    Statement updateQuery = null;

    try {
        updateQuery = dbConnection.createStatement();
        updateQuery.executeUpdate("UPDATE Profile SET height='" + _height + "',weight='" + _weight + "',goalWeight='" + _goalWeight + "',age='" + _age + "' WHERE pName =" + profile.getUsername());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (updateQuery != null) {
                updateQuery.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to close updateCustomer query");
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm trying to update some of the fields that were empty with the Update Profile method and to get the profile that I want to update I wrote "WHERE pName =" + profile.getUsername());" in order to retrieve the record of the user.

Finally in the EditProfile jFrame I wrote this method to pass on the parameters for the updateProfile methods.

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    LoginWindow.dbc.updateProfile(heightTextField.getText(), weightTextField.getText(), goalWeightTextField.getText(), ageTextField.getText());

}
```

Everything compiles but I'm having mySQLSyntaxError which is:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Admin' in 'where clause'

The database is not updated and I don't know how to fix it.

My assumptions is that there is a problem with  "WHERE pName =" + profile.getUsername());" in updateProfile declaration. The "Admin" is the result of profile.getUsername(); and its the actual username of currently logged in user.

Please help.

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Ignoring the joys of SQL injection, print out your SQL statement.  You're probably missing the single quotes.

Comment: If you used `PreparedStatement` instead, you would avoid both SQL Injection attacks and this kind of problems.

Comment: I will edit the code and use PreparedStatemetns thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little syntax error: Your line

```
         updateQuery.executeUpdate("UPDATE Profile SET height='" + _height + "',weight='" + _weight + "',goalWeight='" + _goalWeight + "',age='" + _age + "' WHERE pName =" + profile.getUsername());
```

should read

```
        updateQuery.executeUpdate("UPDATE Profile SET height='" + _height + "',weight='" + _weight + "',goalWeight='" + _goalWeight + "',age='" + _age + "' WHERE pName ='" + profile.getUsername()) + "'";
```

(You need to enclose the `pName` parameter with single quotes.)

...and you **really** need to start using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) as others also suggested.

Answer (score 0):

that exactly the problem. try that:

```
ResultSet rs = userQuery.executeQuery("Select * FROM Profile WHERE pName = '" + profile.getUsername() + "' and password = '" + profile.getPassword() + "' ");
```